# Generate Image with Microsoft .NET Chart Controls Library without Control

Tags: c#, .net, charts

Is it possible to generate images (jpeg, png, etc) using the Microsoft Chart Controls library without instantiating a WinForm or ASP.NET Control class?  All the examples I have seen utilize a control component.  I need to create a library which contains simple methods that take data to be plotted and returns a new chart image.  Examples:

```
public byte[] GeneratePlot(IList<SeriesData> series)
{
    // generate and return JPEG
}
public void GeneratePlot(IList<SeriesData> series, Stream outputStream)
{
    // generate JPEG and write to stream
}
```

If it is not possible:

1. would you recommend
   creating/disposing a new chart
   control each time the user calls the
   GeneratePlot() method?
2. is there
   another .NET library (preferably
   free) that you would recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.IO;
...
    public void GeneratePlot(IList<DataPoint> series, Stream outputStream) {
      using (var ch = new Chart()) {
        ch.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        var s = new Series();
        foreach (var pnt in series) s.Points.Add(pnt);
        ch.Series.Add(s);
        ch.SaveImage(outputStream, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Since Chart inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control, is that going to be expensive to create and dispose for each function call?

Comment: The expense of Control is in getting its Handle property created.  In other words: creating the window.  That doesn't happen here.

Comment: Could we create a tree chart by using this way? :)

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is chart images. Then you can use the chart controls to save to disk.

```
myChart.SaveImage("C:\mypic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Then load that image from the disk. If the charts are only generated once then you can also just check the filesystem for the image first and then only re-render it if it doesnt exist.

Hope this helps.