# Print Graphs in .Net

Tags: .net

Hei

Iam trying to find out how to pring graphs in .net platform . Generate images of graphs from within .net iteself

Comment: what graphs? on screen or on the printer? with an image or with javascript? OR Flash?

Comment: no javascript not flash only think about dot net framework

Comment: Your question is **very** vague. Please be more specific and maybe add some code examples. That will give you the best answers. And how is this related to jQuery?

Comment: do you mean you want to be able to generate images of graphs from within .Net itself?

Comment: Try to flesh your question out, are you trying to print graphs made in wpf, silverlight, a third party control?

Comment: yes i meant to generate images of graphs from within .net iteself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using ZedGraph for a long time without any issues. I have been able to solve all my graphing issues using ZedGRaph.

Comment: I have also used ZedGraph for graphing in .NET in the past. As I recall it was quite easy to use.

Comment: unfortunately noone is maintaining the ZedGraph source code anymore. But its an open source software and you can modify the code yourself. Though it does provide most of the functionalities. The example provided in documentation shows all the graph patterns that it supports.

Comment: In your windows form, you can put a graph panel which can display variou types of graphs.

Comment: i have checked this but its a control i dont want to use control .Do u know another method

Comment: What do you want to use then?

Comment: see the following link was relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823884/generate-image-with-microsoft-net-chart-controls-library-without-control

Answer (score 0):

[Dundas Charts](http://www.dundas.com/) is a popular choice for charting in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

We are using highstock from
http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock