# Create and add Pie Chart to pdf with iTextSharp and another 3rd party

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, .net-core

I'm trying to create a pdf report that contains a pie chart in it. So far I'm using `iTextSharp` to write all of the report but I know I can't generate a chart using that.

Is there another library that I can use to generate an image that I can add to the pdf using `iTextSharp`? I've been searching but all of the ones I've found seem to work for rendering the chart to a View which isn't really what I want.

Just want to generate pie chart, attach to pdf and then download the pdf.

Comment: You can add almost any type of image to pdfs with itext. Just look for a lib, that exports your chart as an image, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823884/generate-image-with-microsoft-net-chart-controls-library-without-control

Comment: @COeDev Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I'm more looking for a lib that will create the chart / image that will work with .net core